# reverting back to an older version of a saved excel 2013 file

Tags: excel, revert

I had an Excel 2013 file consisting of a long list. After making changes, our trainee accidentally clicked 'Save' instead of 'Save As.' Is it possible to revert to the version before it was saved?

So far, in the solutions I've researched on the internet, I've seen information on how to recover "unsaved" files and also how to do it on newer versions of Microsoft Office, but these didn't work for Office 2013. Unfortunately, there is no backup of the file. Therefore, my only option, if available, is to somehow retrieve the old version.

I made a copy of the file and brought it home. If this recovery is possible, does it need to be done only on the computer where the file was originally saved, or can I also access the older version from the copy ?

Comment: So did you work on a copy or the original? I always use a copy when editing important docs that gives me an immediate backup.

Comment: it was not me, but, changes were made on the original copy, unfortunately.